# Why destructor is called when any of these object not going out of scope?

Tags: c++

**When I remove The Destructor from code the output come as i desired but if i free the space manually program become mad :( Please some one help me, I'm Using Code::Blocks IDE and Running in Linux mint OS**
[image]

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class str
{
    char *p;
    int len;
public:
    str() {
        len=0;
        p=NULL;
    }
    str(const char *s);
    str(const str &s);
    ~str() {
        cout<<" Distructor Called ";
        delete p;
    }
    friend str operator+(const str &s,const str &t);
    friend bool operator<=(const str &s,const str &t);
    friend void show(str &s);
};

str::str(const char *s)
{
    len=strlen(s);
    p=new char[len+1];
    strcpy(p,s);
}
str::str(const str &s)
{
    len=s.len;
    p=new char[len+1];
    strcpy(p,s.p);
}

void show(str &s)
{
    cout<<s.p;
}
str operator+(const str &s,const str &t)
{
    str tem;
    tem.len=s.len+t.len;
    tem.p=new char[tem.len+1];
    strcpy(tem.p,s.p);
    strcat(tem.p,t.p);
    return tem;
}
bool operator<=(const str &s,const str &t)
{
    if(s.len<=t.len)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    str s1="New ";
    str s2="York";
    str s3="Delhi";
    str string1,string2,string3;
    string1=s1;
    string2=s1+s2;
    string3=s1+s3;

    cout<<"\nString1 = ";
    show(string1);
    cout<<"\nString2 = ";
    show(string2);
    cout<<"\nString3 = ";
    show(string3);
    cout<<"\n\n";
    if(string1<=string2) {
        show(string1);
        cout<<" Smaller Than ";
        show(string2);
        cout<<"\n";
    } else {
        show(string3);
        cout<<"Smaller Than ";
        show(string1);
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use indentation. And it´s "destructor"

Comment: Destructors are called after the compiler creates temporary copies of objects.  Try using more references.

Comment: You're using the wrong `delete`

Comment: Next time, can you post text of your output, instead of screen snapshots.

Comment: Save yourself troubles.  Switch to using `std::string` for your string needs.  You don't need to worry about dynamic allocation; as the `std::string` performs allocation and deallocation as necessary for you.

Comment: @RajatVerma Why are you using friend void show(str &s) as friend. You could have str.show() method instead

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i Tried This Before when i press c terminal get close and i forget to run in bash, Thaks For suggestion :)

Comment: If you want to implement your own string class for the sake of learning, you can still use `vector<char>` as underlying storage, which would also make your life a bit easier.

Comment: @MartinPerry Ohh... I don't know This Can applied to non static functions too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).
When you don't declare the assignment operator, a default one is generated by the compiler which does the following:

> Assign all the object's members from the corresponding members of the assignment operator's argument, calling the copy assignment operators of the object's class-type members, and **doing a plain assignment of all non-class type (e.g. int or pointer) data members**.

First of all, the above bold text applies to char *p in your class. 
In your operator+ function, tem is an object on stack. When the function ends, tem goes out of scope, and its destructor is called.
So what happens is string1's p is assigned tem's p as per the default assignment operator generated by the compiler, meaning string1's p points to the same memory location as tem's p, which was deallocated after it went out of scope! Hence, string1 does not have the expected value. Later, when string1 goes out of scope and its destructor is called, delete is called on the same memory location for the second time, hence leading to the error shown. Similarly, for string2.

Things will be fine if you overload the assignment operator like this:

```
void str::operator=(const str&s) {
    delete[] p;
    len=s.len;
    p=new char[len+1];
    strcpy(p,s.p);
}
```

In this case, tem's p will be copied over before its destructor is called.

**NOTE:**

1. It works when you remove the destructor because the default
   destructor generated by the compiler does not deallocate the
   allocated memory, but this will leak memory, which is BAD.
2. There is another major flaw in your code. Use **delete[]** for
   deallocating arrays.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks :) Missed that!

Answer (score 1):

You have not overloaded the assignment operator. Because of this the same pointer getting assigned and getting deleted twice which is causing the exception.